# CommonOpenFileDialog opens again after has file chosen

Tags: c#, textbox, microsoft-metro, openfiledialog, metroframework

```
CommonOpenFileDialog cicon = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
        cicon.IsFolderPicker = false;
        cicon.Title = "Choose Icon";
        cicon.Filters.Add(new CommonFileDialogFilter("Executable Files", "*.exe"));
        cicon.Filters.Add(new CommonFileDialogFilter("Icon Files", "*.ico*"));
        if (cicon.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            try
            {
                Image fico = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(cicon.FileName).ToBitmap();
                metroTextBox1.Icon = fico;
            }
            catch (Exception re)
            {
                winmsg msg = new winmsg();
                msg.Title = "Icon Error -  Cannot find any Icon";
                msg.Content = "Path: " + re.Message;
                msg.ShowDialog();
                msg.Dispose();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

I am getting Open file dialog after file chosen, What could be the issue? Above code for click on CustomButton in Metrotextbox.

Comment: I do not see any where in the posted code that would open the dialog a second time. Have you traced this using the debugger? I would think a simple trace would reveal where the second dialog is coming from. I am betting it is coming from somewhere else in the code that you have not shown.

Comment: No, no other code, only on this button, When it run first time it have no issues.. only when choosing second time if decided to change file which already chosen, second time when click on this button open dialog 2 times after click ok,..

Comment: Where does the dialog open a second time when you trace the code?

Comment: It is repeating the same code as above, I used click programatically, may it might me the issue? metroTextBox1.CustomButton.Click += CustomButton_Click;

Comment: Yes, it was the issue, metroTextBox1.CustomButton.Click += CustomButton_Click; was called twice.. Thank you @JohnG